# React Components - avoiding re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, render

Newish to react... I have a component that has an array in state. In the render function, it maps the array to a set of child components which render form components (typically selects). If the user changes one of the select, the child calls onChange, which runs a handler to update the array via the function provided by useState(). The problem - then EVERY child component is re-rendered.  Is there a way to avoid this? React.memo doesn't seem to help, as there are many instances of the same Child component with different props.

Roughly:

```
function Parent() {
  const [ arr, setArr] = useState( <some big array> );

  let handleChange = e => {
    // logic to figure out what needs to be updated
    setArr(<new array>);
  }

  return (
    {
      arr.map( (el, i) =>
        <Child prop1={el} onChange={handleChange}>
      )
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to prevent re-rendering, `React.memo` is the right way to go, however you need to memoize the `handleChange` function otherwise during re-renders each child component will reference a `onChange` function which is different than the previous re-render and hence can't stop re-rendering

```
function Parent() {
  const [ arr, setArr] = useState( <some big array> );

  let handleChange = useCallback(e => {
    // logic to figure out what needs to be updated
    setArr(<new array>);
    // Use functional callback to update state instead of taking it from closure
  }, []); 

  return (
    {
      arr.map( (el, i) =>
        <Child prop1={el} onChange={handleChange}>
      )
    }
  )
}

const Child = React.memo((props) => {
   // Child component logic

})
```

Comment: ah... "Use functional callback to update state instead of taking it from closure" - this was my problem - I had arr in my useCallback dependency array (at the suggestion of the linter). Changing it to a functional form os setArr solved it. Thanks!